# DynamoDB : return list of tables to C# application

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to DynamoDB and trying to write my first database read from C#
It seems to connect (using access and secret key) but then the ListTables method returns the error "inaccessible due to protection level".
This seems odd as lot of people online seem to be using the method in this way.

Can anyone see what i am doing wrong.

I have added a screen capture of the code :

[image]

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I found that i could use an aysnc version that worked :

```
var tableResponse = await client.ListTablesAsync();

if (!tableResponse.TableNames.Contains("JSH_BankTransactions"))
```

Hope this helps someone :-)
John